# Show that $\det\Phi(t)$ is the unique solution of the scalar equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that

$$\det\Phi(t)=\det\Phi(t)\exp\left[\int_{t_0}^{t}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jj}(s)ds\right]$$

is the unique solution of the scalar equation $$y'=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{kk}(t)\right)y$$

satisfying the initial conidition $y(t_0)=\det\Phi(t_0).$